# Can I use variable variables in TWIG?

Tags: symfony, twig

I use symfony2 and TWIG, I want to use some global variables to point to the index of tablet in page:

**app/config/parameters.ini**

```ini
tab_branch="1"
```

**app/config/config.yml**

```
twig:
    globals:
        tab_branch: %tab_branch%
```

**src/ACME/BranchBundle/Controller/defaultController.php**

```php
/**
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction($id) {
    ...
    return array(
        'tab' => 'tab_branch',
    );
}
```

**src/ACME/BranchBundle/Resources/views/default/show.html.twig**

```html
<input type="hidden" id="tablndex" value="{{ {{ tab }} }}" />  //not working
```

I really want to do is to make `{{ tab }}` to be resolved to `tab_branch`, then `{{ tab_branch }}` to be resolved to `1` (just like `$$foo` in PHP), How should I do?

Comment: Sorry, but this just reeks of bad code smell. Maintaining this will be a nightmare. Could you maybe elaborate a bit more on what exactly is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. What I really want to do was just to mark the current tab. Now I use querystring to pass the tabindex between pages, i.e. http://www.abc.com/branch?idx=1, but I really want to discard the querystring, could you suggest other workaround?

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the site you could either check the current route in the template (`{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'FooBar' ? 'foo' : 'bar' }}`) or opt for something more complicated, such as [writing a custom twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) or using [KnpMenuBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done the way you are trying to do it, twig does not work that way. If there are not many possible values for tab, you could do something like:

```
{% if tab == 'tab_branch' %}
    {{tab_branch}}
{% else if tab == 'other_tab' %}
    {{other_tab}}
{% endif %}
```

I know, not very elegant...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've considered that approach, but I'm afraid if I need to add more tabs in the future, I need to dig into all the relevant pages to change the if-logics.

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom function to allow such evaluation.

You may be interested in this proposal [`eval` function](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions/pull/53/files)

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I read the link, but can't see how to make it works, could you show me some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

I refer to variables in other variables anywhere within my data with twig syntax:

```
foo: "{{ bar.baz }}/quu.txt"
bar:
    baz: /tmp
```

Then I render until the result does not change anymore:

```
    while( $template !== ($result = $twig->render($template, $data)) )
    {
        $template = $result;
    }
```

This is

- inelegant: each variable value should be rendered before embedding it
- insufficient: variable names are not rendered before use, so foo.{{i}} won't work
- simple: I don't have to refer to filters or code, just variables.
- small: implementation above is short and hopefully clear. Could be one-line recursive method as well.